# Time-invariance, causality and stability of $h(t)$ of four given systems

Tags: linear-systems, homework, stability, causality

**Question:**

> The impulse response functions of four linear systems $S_1,\ S_2,\ S_3,\ S_4$ are given respectively by
>
> \begin{align}
> h_1(t)&=1\\
> h_2(t)&=u(t)\\
> h_3(t)&=\frac{u(t)}{(t+1)}\\
> h_4(t)&=\exp(-3t)*u(t)
> \end{align}
>
> where $u(t)$ is the unit step function. Which of these systems is time-invariant, causal and stable?
>
> - A) S1
> - B) S2
> - C) S3
> - D) S4

**My Approach:**

we know if $h(t)$ is not equal to $0$ for $t<0$ then the system is non-causal; so option $A$ is non-causal. We also know if the impulse response function of the system is finite then the system is stable; so all the systems are stable. Now what is the condition to check Time-invariancy??

Comment: "We also know if the impulse response function of the system is finite then the system is stable; so all the systems are stable." None of them seem finite to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember the necessary and sufficient condition for [(BIBO)-stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability#Continuous-time_necessary_and_sufficient_condition) of a system described by an impulse response $h(t)$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty\tag{1}$$

If you use condition $(1)$ you will find out that actually only one of the four systems is stable.

The question about time-invariance does not make much sense, because if we assume that the systems are characterized by their impulse response then we already imply that the systems are linear and time-invariant. For linear *time-varying* systems you would need a two-dimensional impulse response, and non-linear systems cannot be characterized by an impulse response.